# How to validate dynamically added div child elements in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I am creating one HTML DIV, it has elements like input, img, textarea, radio, checkbox, dropdown etc these elements are dynamically binding to the div. Sometime DIV may have one element(input text) or it may have multiple elements, those elements are coming from server and binding to the main DIV.
I have to validate the that DIV elements values are added or not while submitting.
I don't want to validate individually in if else block for all the HTML elements.
Is there anyway to validate DIV child elements value added or not ?
Scenario : There is a one section(This is main DIV), that section there are some some questions ( These are sub DIV's like child elements), each section has some round of number to answer the questions like student should answer 5 out of 10 questions so I need to validate how many questions he has answered.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="subSectionDiv template">
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Section_1_SubSection_0">1</label>
                <div class="inner-addonAutoFill right-addon">
                    <img class="autoFillIcon autoFillCls" id="autoFill_Section_1_SubSection_0" onclick="autoFillOtions(id)" src="img/autoFill.png">
                    <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
                        <input class="1_Section_1_SubSection_0_2340 form-control" id="Section_1_SubSection_0" maxlength="15" onblur="hideErrorMessage(this.id)" oninput="maxLengthCheck(this)" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="subSectionDecDiv">
                    <p class="subSectionDescP">1 Desc</p>
                </div>
                <p class="validationP Section_1_SubSection_0"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Section_1_SubSection_1">2</label>
            <div class="ui-select">
                <div aria-disabled="false" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-active" id="Section_1_SubSection_1-button">
                    <span class="form-control mobile-selectmenu-disabled">1</span><select class="form-control" id="Section_1_SubSection_1" onchange="hideErrorMessage(this.id)">
                        <option value="1">
                            1
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">
                            2
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">
                            3
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">
                            4
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="subSectionDecDiv">
                <p class="subSectionDescP">2 Desc</p>
            </div>
            <p class="validationP Section_1_SubSection_1"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Section_1_SubSection_2">3</label>
            <div class="ui-checkbox">
                <label class="checkbox-inline ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-on" onclick="clickOnCheckboxLabel(this);">1</label><input checked="checked" id="ck_1" name="Section_1_SubSection_2" onchange="hideErrorMessage(this.name)" onclick="checkReadOnlyCheckBox(this);" type="checkbox" value="1">
            </div>
            <div class="ui-checkbox">
                <label class="checkbox-inline ui-checkbox-off ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left" onclick="clickOnCheckboxLabel(this);">2</label><input id="ck_2" name="Section_1_SubSection_2" onchange="hideErrorMessage(this.name)" onclick="checkReadOnlyCheckBox(this);" type="checkbox" value="2">
            </div>
            <div class="ui-checkbox">
                <label class="checkbox-inline ui-checkbox-off ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left" onclick="clickOnCheckboxLabel(this);">3</label><input id="ck_3" name="Section_1_SubSection_2" onchange="hideErrorMessage(this.name)" onclick="checkReadOnlyCheckBox(this);" type="checkbox" value="3">
            </div>
            <div class="ui-checkbox">
                <label class="checkbox-inline ui-checkbox-off ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left" onclick="clickOnCheckboxLabel(this);">4</label><input id="ck_4" name="Section_1_SubSection_2" onchange="hideErrorMessage(this.name)" onclick="checkReadOnlyCheckBox(this);" type="checkbox" value="4">
            </div>
            <div class="ui-checkbox">
                <label class="checkbox-inline ui-checkbox-off ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left" onclick="clickOnCheckboxLabel(this);">5</label><input id="ck_5" name="Section_1_SubSection_2" onchange="hideErrorMessage(this.name)" onclick="checkReadOnlyCheckBox(this);" type="checkbox" value="5">
            </div>
            <div class="ui-checkbox">
                <label class="checkbox-inline ui-checkbox-off ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left" onclick="clickOnCheckboxLabel(this);">6</label><input id="ck_6" name="Section_1_SubSection_2" onchange="hideErrorMessage(this.name)" onclick="checkReadOnlyCheckBox(this);" type="checkbox" value="6">
            </div>
            <div class="subSectionDecDiv">
                <p class="subSectionDescP">3 Desc</p>
            </div>
            <p class="validationP Section_1_SubSection_2"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="imgUpldDiv">
            <span class="label">4</span> <span></span>
            <div id="syncDiv">
                <span><button class="btn btn-primary ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all" id="Section_1_SubSection_3" onclick="addCandidatePhoto(id);" type="button"><span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btnGlycophin" hidden="true" style="vertical-align:middle"></span> Upload Img</span><input class="imageFileName Section_1_SubSection_3" type="hidden" value="1488948216078.jpg"></button></span>
            </div><span class="imagePreview Section_1_SubSection_3"><img alt="img" class="img-responsive imgSmall" src="file:/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/1488948216078.jpg" style="margin-right:5px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove savedImageRemover Section_1_SubSection_3 1488948216078" id="Section_1_SubSection_3&amp;file:/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/1488948216078.jpg" onclick="removeSavedPhoto(id)"></span></span>
            <div class="subSectionDecDiv" style="display: block;">
                <p class="subSectionDescP">4 Desc</p>
            </div>
            <p class="validationP Section_1_SubSection_3" id="imageErrorSection_1_SubSection_3" style="display: block;"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

subSectionDiv is the main DIV classname and 4 child divs are there.. I have to validate them one by one weather element value is added or not
Please help me

Comment: create a form validation, there some in jquery one ex http://www.formvalidator.net/

Comment: Do in ajax,while you hitting the submit button need to call one function which is containing validate the all fields(dynamical element)

Comment: Create a form and for all of the <input> type elements you could use trivial input validation that comes as an option with HTML5 or use regex for some. For the rest of the non <input> elements use jQuery to verify that everything going on in the DOM is OK.

Comment: Not only input elements.. It may has img tag, dropdown, checkbox and etc.. Please check the above div so will understand clearly and I also I dont want use Form because all html already implemented and can't change now

Comment: " For the rest of the non <input> elements use jQuery to verify that everything going on in the DOM is OK"

Answer (score 0):

```
I have a hack for this.
Add a class (eg:form-elements) to all the inputs,selectbox,textarea and others which you want to validate and try the code below :

$('.form_elements').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('type')=='checkbox'){
            if($(this).prop('checked')){
                //do something
            }
        }else if($(this).attr('type')=='text'){
            if($(this).val()==''){
                //do something
            }
        }else if($(this).attr('type')==undefined){
            if($(this).prop('tagName').toLowerCase()=='select'){
              if($(this).val()==''){
                //do something
              }
            }
        }
   });

you can use this code to validate all the fields in you page. The validation may vary for some tag and if you want validation for any fields kindly make a request.

Hope this is useful
```